# Postgres behave abnormally

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, postgresql, ubuntu-14.04, jboss

I have production application running on `PostgreSQL` database on a on premise Ubuntu System. Recently I have been facing one strange issue, that Postgres service is getting killed itself and then it is restarted.

I am getting below error in `JBoss 7.1` server, which is strange and is not occurring on fixed method or line :

In **server.log** :

> An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend

Then I checked into Postgres log, it shows that,

In Postgres log **postgresql-9.4-main.log** :

> Process was terminated by signal 9

However, I have stopped Jboss server and executed my one query in `PSQL` and received below error :

```
server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Failed.
```

Same exact replication in `AWS Ubuntu`, is running fine with same database. So, I am not able to find actual root cause. Please help.

Kindly note, I have not made any configuration changes in `PostgreSQL`. Let me know, if any other information required.

Comment: Check with `dmesg` if the Postgres process wasn't killed by the oom_killer for taking too much memory.

Comment: Yes I have checked, there is no such thing.

Comment: Nothing was written to any log at the time that happened?

Comment: Updated question, there is no error in dmesg, however there is error in jboss server log and postgres log

Comment: signal 9 is `KILL` ... something killed your database process.

Comment: Yes, that is what I get after searching online. But this is not occuring on fixed time. So, no any other process is running from my end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case,

After so many try, we just `re-install` Postgres with existing data restore. Now, everything is working fine as expected.

If anyone has still any suggestion, post your answer/comment.